# Xamarin Camera Control Photo does not show on device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, camera

I used the following example to work with Camera Control in Xamarin

Example used: [adamped/CameraXF](https://github.com/adamped/CameraXF/blob/master/CameraSample/CameraSample/MainPage.xaml.cs)

Following piece of code works fine in emulator. On device, it takes up the space of an image but image doesn't load. Any leads?

```
private async void CameraButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var photo = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions() { });

    if (photo != null)
        PhotoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return photo.GetStream(); });
}
```

Comment: You should check the original plugin that is used on that sample: [Media Plugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin), also remember always to check for users permissions on android and ios

Comment: Thanks. I checked and followed the original as suggested with same results. I can see the image taken in the Gallery but it doesn't display on app (still works on emulator). All permissions related to Camera and Storage related granted.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the `CachedImage` class from `FFImageLoading`. I have encountered this problem in lower-end devices and using `CachedImage` fixes it.

Here is the repo : https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Docs : https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API

Here is the xaml sample.

```
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
        DownsampleToViewSize="true"
        Source = "http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">
    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

Dont forget to set the `DownsampleToViewSize="true"`.

This should solve your issue.

Comment: This also ends with same result. Please note that image is on device. Could this be a reason? If I set source to some externally hosted image that image is displayed but not the one take from the camera.